# MS SQL Server Subquery error when db contains more than 1 record

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have created two tables one is "Timeclock" another is "Appointment" table. Time **Clock table** contains, for example,

1. 12:00
2. 12:05
3. 12:10
4. 12:15
5. 12:20
6. 12:25
7. 12:30
8. 12:35
9. 12:40 etc...

**Appointment Table.**
When the appointment table contains records (Reservation)

1. Date: 2020-09-26 between From 12:10 to 12:15
2. Date: 2020-09-26 between From 12:20 to 12:30

Then the query result from the **TimeClock** table to be as follows,

1. 12:00
2. 12:05
3. 12:35
4. 12:40 etc...

When I run below query I get an error when the database contains more than 1 records but when DB contains 1 record then it works well. What is the solution?

```sql
SELECT Time24
FROM GlobalSetup.TimeClock
WHERE
  Time24 not between
    (SELECT start_time FROM Customer.Appointment WHERE start_date = '2020-09-26' and EmployeeRecID = 1)
    and
    (SELECT end_time FROM Customer.Appointment WHERE start_date = '2020-09-26' and EmployeeRecID = 1)
  and Every5Mins = 1
Order By Time24
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: *"What is the solution?"* Then ensure you're subquery returns 1 row, likely by changing the lateral join conditions (or adding some in this case) or change the query as you have a design flaw with it. The fact that you are repeating subquery, and a lack of a join criteria, the second seems the most likely.

Comment: @Rozmi has your initial question been answered?  Without having that confirmation it could be counterproductive to get to work on your follow up.  Since there's no limit to the number of times you can ask new questions on SO, you could speed up getting your answers by marking this one and then moving on to the next.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want times that are not between appointments.  `NOT EXISTS` as suggested by GSerg is appropriate.  I'm not sure why that answer was deleted.

I would write this as:

```
SELECT tc.Time24
FROM GlobalSetup.TimeClock tc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Customer.Appointment a
                  WHERE a.EmployeeRecID = 1 AND
                        tc.Time24 >= a.start_time AND
                        tc.Time24 <= a.end_time
                 ) AND
     tc.Every5Mins = 1 AND
     tc.Time24 >= '2020-09-26' AND
     tc.Time24 < '2020-09-27'
ORDER BY Time24;
```

The above assumes that the start and end times include the date.  If that is not true, then an additional comparison is needed:

```
SELECT tc.Time24
FROM GlobalSetup.TimeClock tc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Customer.Appointment a
                  WHERE a.EmployeeRecID = 1 AND
                        a.start_date = '2020-09-26' AND
                        tc.Time24 >= a.start_time AND
                        tc.Time24 <= a.end_time
                 ) AND
     tc.Every5Mins = 1 AND
     tc.Time24 >= '2020-09-26' AND
     tc.Time24 < '2020-09-27'
ORDER BY Time24;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, appreciated your prompt response. I have created two tables one is "Timeclock" another is "Appointment" table. Time Clock table contains, for example, 12:00, 12:05, 12:10, 12:15, 12:20, 12:25, 12:30, 12:35, 12:40 etc... When the appointment table booked between 12:10 to 12:15 and another booked between 12:20 to 12:30 then I don't want query result display between these booked time

Comment: @Rozmi . . . Details about the data belong in the question, not in a comment.  Fix the question.